# Как создать многопользовательский сервер или откуда его скачать?

Tags: java

Как создать многопользовательский сервер или откуда его скачать?

цель такая что сервер, должен ждать подключения от клиентов. Если пришел клиент с номером 1, то он кидает его в 1 группу, после если придет клиент с номером 2 то кинет в группу 2. Если придет клиент с номером 1 то кинет в 1 группу и группа будет сформироанная для них, тобишь они смогут общаться только между собой. Как это провернуть? есть схема какая - нибудь, долго думал и кодил все не то. Устал уже просто

```
public class Main {
    public static Socket socket1,socket2;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        ServerSocket serverSocket=new ServerSocket(7475);
        while (true){
            Socket socket=serverSocket.accept();
            String asd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream())).readLine();

            if (asd.equals("0")){
                socket1=socket;
                MySocket(socket,0);
            }

            if (asd.equals("1")){
                socket2=socket;
                MySocket(socket,1);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void MySocket(Socket socket,int a){
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            String exit="";
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    while (!exit.equals("exit")){
                        String asd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream())).readLine();
                        if (asd.equals("exit")) exit="exit";
                        BufferedWriter bufferedWriter=null;
                        if (a==0) {
                            bufferedWriter=new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket2.getOutputStream()));
                        }
                        if (a==1) {
                            bufferedWriter=new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket1.getOutputStream()));
                        }
                        bufferedWriter.write(asd);
                        bufferedWriter.flush();
                    }
                    socket.close();
                    System.out.println("CLOSE");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

Comment: xD не успел создать вопрос уже -4, щяс закроют небось)

Сто пудово Nofate♦ свой минус опять поставил)

Comment: Покажите, до чего докодились и что в этом не работает :)

Comment: @D-side, щя код скину, там каша, я ни как логику не могу реализовать, вроде в голове обдумываю все, пишу на листочке, начинаю кодить и нифига не работает

Comment: Автор, обращение к тебе, если за тебя кто-то напишет этот сокет сервер, то ты его не сможешь развивать, твори свое чудо, а так код очень плохой.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Хватит уже сырые сокеты использовать, люди (:

Есть много прекрасных библиотек, которые многие вещи за вас делают. Мы для своей игры используем [Netty](http://netty.io/), к примеру.

У вас же проблема больше концептуальная. Надо разделить логику, хотя бы на 2 части:

1. Сервис-мм, который играет роль матч мейкера. Он как раз следит за распределением игроков.
2. Сервис, играющий роль инстанса. На нём, собственно, играют люди. Можно сделать сервис-комнату (для одной группы игроков). Или сделать сервис, где будет список комнат, чтоб сэкономить ресурсы.

После распределения мм сервис выдаёт ip:port и пароль к сервису-комнате и игроки подсоединяются к ней.

Это мало-мальски рабочая конфигурация. Если на машине подразумевается несколько игровых инстансов, то над ними хорошо бы создать сервис-менеджер, который следит за их состоянием. Тогда ММ будет взаимодействовать с этим сервисом, а он уже будет выбирать конкретный инстанс-комнату.

Я описал упрощённую архитектуру на подобии той, что мы используем.

Comment: Ничего не ясно, смысл архитектуры ясна, но сама логика реализации так и не понятно по вашему тексту. И толку что вы ответили на вопрос? будто просто мнение оставили свое, а ответа так не получил.

Лучше бы книжку дали откуда вы про эту систему вычитали, чем так кратко писать новичку.

Comment: @xTIGRx такие вещи кратко не описать. Не понятно, какой вы хотите ответ получить.